# Incorrect header from numpy savetxt

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have two python lists like the following:

`a = [1,2,3,4,5]`

`b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

A convenient way to save these to csv files is to just use numpy with the following syntax:

`np.savetxt("f1.csv", np.column_stack((a,b)),delimiter=",", fmt="%s, %s",header=" val1, val2")`

But the output csv is like this with a `#` before val1 instead of just val1, the name specified in the header:

```
# val1  val2
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   c
3   4   d
4   5   e
```

I am using python 3.5.3 and numpy==1.13.1. Is it some encoding issue? What am I missing?

Comment: play with the `comments` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @hpaulj the `comments` parameter does the trick:

```
np.savetxt("f2.csv", np.column_stack((a,b)),delimiter=",", fmt="%s, %s",header=" val1, val2", comments="")
```

More information about the usage of `comments` can be found in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).